# spinner with ItemSelected

Tags: android, android-spinner

i have  spinner with array that i create in a string.xml which called array.spinner_title

how can i do the on item select her so i can get the item selected

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( SendTeacher.this,
                R.array.spinner_title, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
         spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {


                    // Do something

                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {

                }
            });
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question , you want to get the selected item.

In:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

     CharSequence item = (CharSequence)adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

}
```

For custom adapter which can contain any other objects (not only CharSequence), see this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) for example